# Service.onDestroy() is called directly after creation, anyway the Service does its work

Tags: android

I built a Service and it didn't work as expected, so I debugged it. During debugging, I saw that the service's onDestroy() method is called directly after returning from onCreate(). When I comment out the cleanup that happens in onDestroy(), the service does its work, but this should not be my solution. So my question is, why is onDestroy() called so early and why is the service running anyway? Or how can I prevent onDestroy() from being called at the wrong time?

For your information: I've subclassed IntentService.

Thanks for any help.

Binabik

Comment: Can you post an stripped down version of your code that exhibits this problem?

Comment: I think we need to know how the service is started and why you did not just subclassed Service class.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are subclassing IntentService you should be using [onHandleIntent(Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onHandleIntent%28android.content.Intent%29) for the lifecycle of your service. Your service might be moving to onDestroy quickly becuase you do not have code inside of onHandleIntent. Although without your code I cannot say for sure.

Also it might aways move to onDestroy quickly because IntentService is auto threaded for you and might just launch the worker thread which calls onHandleIntent and move to onDestroy.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I checked it again and now I understand that using an IntentService was a bad idea because an IntentService stops itself after returning from onHandleIntent(). I even found that in the documentation: "The IntentService does the following: [...] Stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you never have to call stopSelf()." I'll try with a "normal" Service.