# Android onHandleIntent is never called

Tags: android, android-studio

I can get registration id from GCM server and catch the notification that is sent with [gcm-alert Push Notification online tool](http://gcm-alert.appspot.com/) but the **onHandleIntent** method of the **GcmIntentService** is never called.
There is an interesting thing that **onDestroy** method is called. Any help will be appreciated.

**GcmIntentService.java**

```
package ondermerol.com.studiopushtest;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.*;
/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p/>
 * TODO: Customize class - update intent actions, extra parameters and static
 * helper methods.
 */
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    private final static String Tag="---IntentServicetest";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super("GcmIntentService");
        Log.d(Tag, "Constructor");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(Tag, "onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.d(Tag, "onStart()");
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void setIntentRedelivery(boolean enabled) {
        Log.d(Tag, "setIntentRedelivery()");
        super.setIntentRedelivery(enabled);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(Tag, "IntentServicetest is onHandleIntent!");

    }
```

**GcmBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    public GcmBroadcastReceiver() {
    }

    // Receives the broadcast directly from GCM service
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                ondermerol.com.studiopushtest.GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ondermerol.com.studiopushtest" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="ondermerol.com.studiopushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="ondermerol.com.studiopushtest.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

   <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="ondermerol.com.studiopushtest" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:enabled="true"
            android:name="ondermerol.com.studiopushtest.GcmIntentService">
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I can give other two classes if needed.

Comment: how did you know it's not called???

Comment: I put break points on evey method of GcmIntentService and see that it is not called although other methods of it is called.

Comment: I solved it, you can see my answer. Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that it is called but the break point in that method is never works because **IntentService** works in another thread.

And the **onDestroy** is called because an IntentService stops itself after returning from onHandleIntent().

Thanks for this answer [Service.onDestroy() is called directly after creation, anyway the Service does its work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7571021/1351327)

Comment: " break point in that method is never works because IntentService works in another thread" well, that's not true. I was adding breakpoints inside the `IntentService#onHandleIntent()` and Android Studio was stopping the execution just fine, so it can work with breakpoints in threads other than the main thread. the issue most likely was caused by the `onStartCommand()` override.

Comment: I removed the onStartCommand() override and there is no change. Maybe there is a problem with my test device (Samsung Galaxy Note 2) or android studio.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on the `IntentService#onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)`:

> ```
> /**
>  * You should not override this method for your IntentService. Instead,
>  * override {@link #onHandleIntent}, which the system calls when the IntentService
>  * receives a start request.
>  * @see android.app.Service#onStartCommand
>  */
> ```

I see that you overridden `onStartCommand()` in your implementation, try to stick with the default one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, I solved it, I have to use logs more often :)