# How to keep object variable alive after service onDestroy in Android?

Tags: java, android, intentservice, mediarecorder, recording

I have a `MediaRecorder` in my `IntentService` class.

I want to

1. Run an `IntentService` to start recording audio
2. Run an `IntentService` to stop recording audio

I use `IntentService` because I want the audio recording to run even when my phone screen is turned off. Service runs in the background, so this is a good approach, right?

Anyways, I initiate my `MediaRecorder` in my `IntentService` at Step #1.
At Step#2, my instantiated `MediaRecorder` is NULL. It seems that all variable values inside the `IntentService` are reset, because the service ends and calls `onDestroy`.

What should I do? How do I keep a reference to my `MediaRecorder` ?

Update: Pasting my `IntentService` class

```
package com.dan190.enregistreur.BackgroundService;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import com.dan190.enregistreur.RecordedFilesActivity;
import com.dan190.enregistreur.Util.RecordingStatus;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Dan on 17/03/2017.
 */
public class RecorderService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = RecorderService.class.getName();

    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public RecorderService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public RecorderService() {
        super("RecorderService");
    }
    /**
     * Handles intent.
     * Unwraps intent to find out if we need to start, pause, or stop
     * @param intent
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent");

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        int status = bundle.getInt(RecordingStatus.RECORDING_STATUS_KEY);
        switch (status) {
        case RecordingStatus.STANDBY:
            //do nothing
            break;
        case RecordingStatus.RECORDING:
            //if mediaPlayer is null, initiate
            //set datasource
            //prepare
            //record
            Log.d(TAG, "start recording");
            startRecording();
            break;
        case RecordingStatus.PAUSED:
            //pause
            Log.d(TAG, "pause recording");
            break;
        case RecordingStatus.STOPPED:
            //stop
            Log.d(TAG, "stop recording");
            stopRecording();
            Intent newIntent = new Intent(this, RecordedFilesActivity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent);
            break;
        case RecordingStatus.OPENDIR:
            //open recorded files
            Log.d(TAG, "open directory");
            getFileName();
            Intent newIntent2 = new Intent(this, RecordedFilesActivity.class);
            startActivity(newIntent2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * File stuff
     */
    private static String pathName,
    fileName;

    public static String getPath() {
        return pathName;
    }

    public static String getFilePath() {
        return fileName;
    }

    private String getFileName() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
        pathName = getPackageName();
        PackageInfo p = null;
        try {
            p = m.getPackageInfo(pathName, 0);
        } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pathName = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;

        //        fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/Recordings";
        fileName = pathName;
        fileName += String.format("/%d_%d_%d_%d_%d_%d.3gp", calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + 1, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));

        return fileName;

    }

    /**
     * Recorder stuff
     */
    private void startRecording() {
        String fileName = getFileName();
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("file name is %s", fileName));

        if (mMediaRecorder == null) mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        //NOTE that mediaRecorder cannot pause for API < 24, which is Android 7.0
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getFileName());
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        } catch(IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        try {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
            mMediaRecorder.reset();
        } catch(RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        releaseMediaRecorder();
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
            mMediaRecorder.release();
            mMediaRecorder = null;
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "mediaRecroder is already Null");
        }

    }

    /**
     * Lifecycle stuff
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }

}
```

Comment: Paste the IntentService class here

Comment: Done @ZeeshanShabbir

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using Service instead of Intent service.

This post proved helpful. [Service.onDestroy() is called directly after creation, anyway the Service does its work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570885/service-ondestroy-is-called-directly-after-creation-anyway-the-service-does-i)

Basically, IntentService is designed so that it will immediately stop all services after the code within onHandleIntent is finished. Thus, I was never able to keep my MediaRecorder alive.

With a normal Service, I am able to have more control over the lifecycle of my service. I can start and stop it when I want to. With IntentService, this is not possible.